# submit from on selcted value when page load

Tags: php

This is my php form i  want to submit from on selected value on page load how it's possible. on page load i want to select Architect as a selected value.

```
<select name="with" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['market']) && !empty($_REQUEST['market'])) { ?> onChange="if(this.value=='1'){window.location='?market=<?php echo $_REQUEST['market']; ?>&with=1'} else if(this.value=='2') {window.location='?market=<?php echo $_REQUEST['market']; ?>&with=2'} else {window.location='<?php echo $baseUrl."viewMeetings.php?market=".$_REQUEST['market']; ?>'}; <?php } else { ?> onChange=" if(this.value=='1'){window.location='?with=1'} else 
if(this.value=='2') {window.location='?with=2'} else {window.location='<?php echo $baseUrl."viewMeetings.php"; ?>'}; <?php } ?>">
   <option value="" <?php if(!isset($_REQUEST['with'])) { echo "selected=selected"; } ?>>ALL </option>
   <option value="1" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['with'])) { if($_REQUEST['with']==1) { echo "selected=selected"; } } ?>>Customer</option>
   <option value="2" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['with'])) { if($_REQUEST['with']==2) { echo "selected=selected"; } } ?> >Architect</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try not using inline javascript. I am not the best at Javascripting but see if this works. Your description is not very clear so hopefully this is what you are looking for! The loading and so forth technically works, but whether it works like you are expecting is another story:

**jQuery Libraries**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**Select Button (Add id)**

```
<select name="with" id="with-it">
  <option value="" <?php if(!isset($_REQUEST['with'])) { echo "selected=selected"; } ?>>ALL </option>
  <option value="1" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['with'])) { if($_REQUEST['with']==1) { echo "selected=selected"; } } ?>>Customer</option>
  <option value="2" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['with'])) { if($_REQUEST['with']==2) { echo "selected=selected"; } } ?> >Architect</option>
</select>
```

**Script for onChange**

```
<script>
    $("#with-it").change(function() {
        var ValueSet    =   $(this).val();

        <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['market'])) { ?>
        if(ValueSet == '1') {
                window.location='?market=<?php echo $_REQUEST['market']; ?>&with='+ValueSet
            }
        else if(ValueSet == '2') {
                window.location='?market=<?php echo $_REQUEST['market']; ?>&with='+ValueSet
            }
        else {
            window.location='<?php echo $baseUrl."viewMeetings.php?market=".$_REQUEST['market']; ?>'}
        <?php }
        else { ?>

        if(ValueSet == '1'){
                window.location='?with=1';
            }
        else if(ValueSet =='2') {
                window.location = '?with=2';
            }
        else {
                window.location = '<?php echo $baseUrl."viewMeetings.php"; ?>';
            }
        <?php } ?>
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hopefully it's what you are looking for.